# Can one element in struct access another element of itself in C?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to declare a int num in struct S. Then the same struct should also have a array B of size num(So `B` will access `num` from it's own struct).

while in a function, I can do,

```
func(int A)
{
    int max=A; //I could use A directly, I am just trying to explain my plan.
    int B[max];
}
```

same won't work for struct as such,

```
struct S {
    int num;
    int data[num]; //this is wrong, num is undeclared
};
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Objects cannot access other objects in C. That is not OOP. But you are not "accessing" an object, but use the value of a variable array size. Use a _flexible array member_ and store its size in 'max' (allthough I would call it `length` or similar)..

Comment: structure can not be dynamic, it will be of fixed value..

Comment: Even outside a struct, a declaration like `int data[num];` does not mean that `data` will change size when you change `num`... it means `data` will have a fixed size that depends on what value `num` has *at the point where `data` is declared*.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a flexible array member:

```
struct S {
    int num;
    int data[];
};

int x = 42; 

struct S *p = malloc(sizeof (struct S) + sizeof (int [x]));
p->num = x;
```

Comment: If `num` is the length of the array, it is better to use that name. Its type should be `size_t`.

Comment: @Olaf I'm reusing the member names used by OP, and there is no requirement for `num` to be a `size_t` if `int` is wide enough for OP values.

Answer (score 4):

There are several problems with

```
struct S {
    int num;
    int data[num]; 
};
```

that cause it to not work the way you want to.

The first is that the `num` being used in the array member declaration isn't the same `num` that's the member of the struct type; the compiler treats the `num` in the array declaration as a regular identifier (*i.e.*, it assumes there's a different variable named `num` in the same scope as the `struct` declaration)<sup>1</sup>.

The second problem is that a `struct` or `union` type may not have a variable-length array as a member<sup>2</sup>.  However, the last member in the struct may have an *incomplete* array type:

```
struct S {
    int num;
    int data[]; 
};
```

Unfortunately, you're still kind of stuck here; if you create an instance of `struct S` like

```
struct S foo;
```

it doesn't actually allocate any space for the array.  You'd need to allocate the struct dynamically:

```
/**
 * Note that sizeof doesn't try to actually dereference foo below
 */
struct S *foo = malloc( sizeof *foo + N * sizeof *foo->arr );
```

to allocate space for the array itself.  Note that you cannot declare an array of `struct S` or use it as a member of another structure or union type if the last member has an incomplete array type. <sup>3</sup>

Honestly, your best option is to define the struct as

```
struct S {
  size_t num;
  int *data;
};
```

and then allocate the memory for `data` as a separate operation from allocating memory for the struct object itself:

```
struct S foo;
foo.num = some_value();
foo.data = malloc( sizeof *foo.data * foo.num );
```

Since `struct S` now has a known size, you can declare arrays of it, and you can use it as a member of another struct or union type:

```
struct S blah[10];

struct T {
  struct S s;
  ...
};
```

---

<sup>1.   C supports four different name spaces - label names (disambiguated by label syntax), `struct`/`union`/`enum` tag names (disambiguated by the presence of the `struct`, `union`, or `enum` keyword), `struct` and `union` member names (disambiguated by the `.` and `->` component selection operators), and everything else.  Since the `num` in your array declaration is not an operand of `.` or `->`, the compiler treats it as a regular variable name.


2. 6.7.2.1/9: "A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a variably modified type."


2. 6.2.7.1/3: A structure or union shall not contain a member with incomplete or function type (hence,
a structure shall not contain an instance of itself, but may contain a pointer to an instance
of itself), except that the last member of a structure with more than one named member
may have incomplete array type; such a structure (and any union containing, possibly
recursively, a member that is such a structure) shall not be a member of a structure or an
element of an array.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the member `num` is not declared until the end of the struct definition, which ends at the last `}`.

Second, how would it make sense to set the array size to be the value of an uninitialized variable?

What I think you attempt to do with `int B[max]` is to create a variable length array (VLA). But that won't work either, as they are explicitly forbidden inside structs. 6.7.2.1/9:

> A member of a structure or union may have any complete object type other than a
>   variably modified type.

What you could do instead is to declare a flexible array member, as demonstrated in the answer by Ouah.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the compiler complains when you "flexibly declare" the array in the struct in global memory, is because global memory can only be allocated (declared) at compile-time and at compile time all sizes must be known. (The value of a variable is not known at compile time by definition.)

The reason it accepts a flexible array in a function, is because the function's local variables are created at the moment the function is entered and then the compiler can accept a variable size. (It boils down to the compiler allocating more memory on the stack and offsetting all accesses to local variables with the size - but different compilers could have a different approach.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int size;
struct S {
    int num;
    int a[size];    // illegal: size must be known at compile time
};

int f(int size)
{
    int a[size];   // legal as a is allocated on the stack
    ....
}
```

The following would be legal:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define A_SIZE 10
struct S {
    int num;
    int a[A_SIZE];    // legal: A_SIZE is known at compile time
};
```

P.s.: I am not a C99 programmer; I may have some mistakes here.

Comment: OP's `struct` does not define an object. That is just the `struct` type definition. However, the syntax is not possible, but `[]` (_flexible array member_) would be allowed.

Comment: But when I would create the struct variable, I would provide num as, `struct S={10};`. should it not work then?

Comment: I don't understand your syntax, or it is an initializer but it doesn't have enough fields to initialize S. So no, it won't work. But you can use a constant - I'll update my post to show you.

Comment: I mean I would initialize it as `struct S={var};`. I used 10 as an example, actually the value would be inputted from the user. I think I can initialize only few elements from struct. Am I wrong?

Comment: There are many reasons why the code won't compile. To say that it is just because `num` isn't a compile-time constant isn't really correct. The compiler complains that `num` is not defined, and that is because the struct definition is not yet complete when `num` is referenced.